# Arrays of Variables, is it possible?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a situation where I have created a list of variables containing a lot of logic, I have simplified this for ease of reading.

My aim is to be able to wrap an array variable around the entire list of variables I've created to then call upon further down my document, rather than call each variable (with `<xsl:value-of select="$variableName"/>`) one after another (there are around 150+).

Here is what I've tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="array1" as="element()*">
    <xsl:variable name="one">
        <!-- Lots of logic here to produce an output of 1 -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="two"    select="'2'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="three"  select="'3'"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$array1[.]"/>
```

----**Expected:** 1 2 3

-----**Output:** NULL

```
<xsl:variable name="array2" as="element()*">
    <test>A</test>
    <test>B</test>
    <test>C</test>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$array2[.]"/>
```

-----**Expected:** A B C

-----**Output:** A B C

As you can see, `array2` outputs correctly, but not `array1`.
Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Comment: You might call it an array but you have a sequence of elements as your type declaration `element()*` indicates. As for your first snippet, it is not clear what you expect there, the inner variables are not used anywhere.

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is a sequence of variable values within the array variable. I couldn't see one that could be something like variable()*....Maybe I'm trying to tackle this in the wrong approach

Comment: The value of an `xsl:variable` is the sequence constructed within, there is nothing like nested variables or like a data type `variable()` so I am not sure what you expect to achieve there. You can nest `xsl:variable` elements but that only makes sense as far as you want to use the value of the nested `xsl:variable` then in the sequence constructor e.g. `<xsl:variable name="foo-elements" as="element(foo)*"><xsl:variable name="transformed-bar-elements"><xsl:apply-templates select="//bar"/></xsl:variable><xsl:sequence select="$transformed-bar-elements//foo"/></xsl:variable>`.